# AngularJS change variable with console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular and I made a simple game, I'm using [ng-inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) to view current variable value, but how can I cahange variable value with browser console?

Comment: you could take use of debugger & put it in controller..then play with scope in console..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get `$scope` from `jquery`/`jqlite` selector like desribed [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), see function `scope()`. Change model attached to `$scope` and call `$apply` on this scope.

So the full script will be:

```
var $scope = $(#game-result-score-value).scope();
$scope.$apply(function () { $scope.score = 1;  });
```

Comment: This works in some way, I get all variables like this, but I need value of only 1 variable. Here is the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/79bpu4

Comment: $scope.$apply(function () { $scope.score = 1; }); This should change value of score to 1.

Comment: I already tried that with `$scope.score = 1;` and now yours too, and I still get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined"
SS: http://prntscr.com/79bv55

Comment: $scope = $(#game-result-score-value).scope(); You must initialize $scope before using it.

Comment: Thank you!! I just started angular :)

Answer (score 6):

You may access a **controller's scope** in the console by:

1. Select the node in the elements tab by clicking on it.
2. Execute `var scope = angular.element($0).scope();`

`$0` is a reference to the selected DOM element in the console (webkit).

If instead you want access to **factory/service variables** you may use the injector method:

```
var injector = angular.element($0).injector();

var srv = injector.get('serviceName');
```

Answer (score 0):

- Select the node in the elements tab by clicking on it.
- $0 is a reference to the selected DOM element in the console (webkit).

  > var scope = angular.element($0).scope();
  >   console.log(scope);
  >   scope.score=1;
  >   scope.$apply(function () { });
  >   assuming score is a scope variable